# Approx net postdoc salary in Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, salary, tax-deductions

I’m planning to move to NL for a postdoc position. My gross monthly salary will be 3703 euros and I’m pretty sure I’ll qualify for the 30% tax ruling. I’m unmarried and so will be moving there alone. Could anybody give me an idea of what would my net salary be after the tax and insurance deductions (roughly)? I’m not taking into account the yearly bonus and other small allowances right now.

Answer (score 0):

According to this calculator https://thetax.nl/?startFrom=Month&selectedYear=2023&older=false&allowance=false&socialSecurity=true&hoursAmount=40&ruling=false&income=3703 for 2023 your net monthly income would be €2865

Comment: Your net figure struck me as way too low and indeed, it looks like you forgot to tick the 30% ruling checkbox. With it the net pay comes out at a little over 3300, in line with my experience.